# VRP - Clarke and Wright implementation in python unable to find routes

Tags: python, vehicle-routing, heuristics

Here's my attempt to implement the clarke and wright algorithm with the following constraints: maximum truck capacity, maximum distance traveled by a truck.

The algorithm takes a distance matrix to calculate the distance between two nodes, and a weights array, in which each element is the demand -weight- of a specific node.

The code seems to work fine with the predefined variables,- max_distance, max_capacity..
but once I want to try with other values it either prints the same routes, or false ones.

You can check and test the live code here: [LINK TO LIVE CODE](https://onlinegdb.com/tEG0oyBr-)

Or

Here's the complete code:

```
import numpy as np

# Maximum capacity of the vehicle
max_capacity = 100

# Maximum travel distance of the vehicle
max_distance = 500

# Index of the depot node
depot = 0

# Weight of each node
weights = [42, 16, 32, 1, 21, 29, 27, 50, 46]

# Distance matrix representing the distances between nodes
distance_matrix = np.array([[0, 50, 50, 80, 60, 45, 80, 35, 105],
                           [50, 0, 30, 45, 65, 80, 120, 55, 110],
                           [50, 30, 0, 80, 90, 90, 105, 35, 75],
                           [80, 45, 80, 0, 45, 85, 155, 95, 150],
                           [60, 65, 90, 45, 0, 45, 130, 95, 150],
                           [45, 80, 90, 85, 45, 0, 95, 75, 140],
                           [80, 120, 105, 155, 130, 95, 0, 75, 100],
                           [35, 55, 35, 95, 95, 75, 75, 0, 70],
                           [105, 110, 75, 150, 150, 140, 100, 70, 0]])

# Savings dictionary to store the savings for each pair of nodes
savings = dict()

# Number of nodes
n = distance_matrix.shape[0]

# List to store the routes
routes = []

# List to keep track of assigned nodes

assigned_nodes = []

# List to keep track of assigned pairs of nodes
assigned_pairs = []

# Calculate savings
for i in range(1, n):
        for j in range(1, n):
            if i != j:
                key = (i, j)
                savings[key] = distance_matrix[0][i] + distance_matrix[0][j] - distance_matrix[i][j]
                
# Sort savings
sorted_savings = sorted(savings.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)


# Create the first route with the first node in the sorted savings array
key, value = sorted_savings[0]
node1, node2 = key
first_route = [0, 0]

if distance_matrix[depot][node1] < max_distance and weights[node1] < max_capacity:
    assigned_nodes.append(node1)
    first_route.insert(1, node1)
    routes.append(first_route)
    
    
# Loop through the sorted savings
for key, value in sorted_savings:
    node1, node2 = key
    
    # Check if either node of the pair is already assigned to a route
    for route in routes:
        if node1 in route or node2 in route:
            if (node1 in route and not node2 in assigned_nodes) and not ([node1, node2] in assigned_pairs or [node2, node1] in assigned_pairs):
                if node1 == route[1] or node1 == route[len(route)-2]:
                    # Check if the node can be inserted at the beginning or end of the route
                    if node1 == route[1]:
                        if sum(distance_matrix[depot][node] for node in route )+ distance_matrix[node1][node2] + distance_matrix[node2][depot] < max_distance\
                            and sum(weights[node] for node in route) + weights[node2]:
                                node1_index = route.index(node1)
                                route.insert(node1_index, node2)
                                assigned_nodes.append(node2)
                                assigned_pairs.append([node1, node2])
                    elif node1 == route[len(route)-2]:
                            if sum(distance_matrix[depot][node] for node in route )+ distance_matrix[node1][node2] + distance_matrix[node2][depot] < max_distance\
                            and sum(weights[node] for node in route) + weights[node2]:
                                node1_index = route.index(node1) + 1
                                route.insert(node1_index, node2)
                                assigned_nodes.append(node2)
                                assigned_pairs.append([node1, node2])
                                
                else: 
                    new_route = [0, node2, 0]
                    routes.append(new_route)
                    
            # Create a new route with the node if it cannot be added to an existing route
            elif (node2 in route and not node1 in assigned_nodes) and not ([node1, node2] in assigned_pairs or [node2, node1] in assigned_pairs):
                # Check if the other node of the pair can be inserted into the route
                if node2 == route[1] or node2 == route[len(route)-2]:
                    if node2 == route[1]:
                        if sum(distance_matrix[depot][node] for node in route )+ distance_matrix[node2][node1] + distance_matrix[node1][depot] < max_distance\
                            and sum(weights[node] for node in route) + weights[node1]:
                            node2_index = route.index(node2)
                            route.insert(node2_index, node1)
                            assigned_nodes.append(node1)
                            assigned_pairs.append([node2, node1])
                            
                    elif node2 == route[len(route)-2]:
                            if sum(distance_matrix[depot][node] for node in route )+ distance_matrix[node2][node1] + distance_matrix[node1][depot] < max_distance\
                            and sum(weights[node] for node in route) + weights[node1]:
                                node2_index = route.index(node2) + 1
                                route.insert(node2_index, node1)
                                assigned_nodes.append(node1)
                                assigned_pairs.append([node2, node1])
                else: 
                    # Create a new route with the node if it cannot be added to an existing route
                    new_route = [0, node1, 0]
                    routes.append(new_route)
                    assigned_nodes.append(node1)
                    
    # Check if both nodes of the pair are unassigned and can be inserted into a new route
    if (not node1 in route and not node2 in route ) and (not node1 in assigned_nodes and not node2 in assigned_nodes) \
        and not ([node1, node2] in assigned_pairs or [node2, node1] in assigned_pairs):
        if distance_matrix[depot][node1] + distance_matrix[node1][node2] + distance_matrix[node2][depot] < max_distance\
            and weights[node1] + weights[node2] < max_capacity:
            new_route = [0, node1, node2, 0]
            routes.append(new_route)
            assigned_nodes.append(node1)
            assigned_nodes.append(node2)
            assigned_pairs.append([node1, node2])
            
# Print the routes
for route in routes:
    i = routes.index(route)
    result = " -> ".join(str(x) for x in route)
    print(f"Route {i + 1}: {result}")
```

Comment: Since you tagged vrpy, why don't you use the source-code from vrpy ? [here](https://github.com/Kuifje02/vrpy/blob/master/vrpy/clarke_wright.py) is vrpy's clarke and wright heuristic.

Comment: I will give it a look thank you